# Force git in VSCode to look down, not look up

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm not sure if this has a `git` solution or a `VSCode` solution, but given the following structure:

```
+ root_dir (in git repo A)
+-+ sub_dir
  +-- .repo
  +-+ srcs
    +-- source_dir1 (in git repo B)
    +-- source_dir2 (in git repo C)
```

I have `sub_dir` open in `VSCode` via the `Open Folder` option, but I only see changes to `repo A` in the `Source Control` window.

If I do `rm -rf root_dir/.git` then `VSCode` sees `repo B` and `repo C`. Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve removing the root `.git` directory?

Comment: User error. You need to put repo A in one place, B in another and C in a 3rd different place.  Perhaps all three should be "parallel" to each other (as B and C are).

Comment: The folder structure seems odd. From `.repo`, I guess it could be AOSP related workspace that has a lot of git repositories. But for all I know, the `repo` workspace isn't supposed to be embedded inside another git repository.

Comment: @ElpieKay It's actually our own structure where `sub_dir` is mounted into a Docker container so if it is used from Docker the `root_dir` cannot be seem. I agree it is odd, but I'm just wanting to see if there's a way round the issue, perhaps using `.gitignore`?

Comment: `.gitignore` doesn't help in this case. Maybe you could rename `root_dir`'s `.git` back and forth when necessary, although it could be annoying.

Comment: Just ... restructure ... your ... directories!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better support for nested repositories (that are not submodules) is tracked as [VSCode issue 37947](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/37947), which is currently (2021-02-12) open, with no indication of recent work or plans.

The issue report mentions a workaround, however:

1. Start with an empty workspace.
2. Add inner folder `source_dir1` to the workspace.
3. Add inner folder `source_dir2` to the workspace.
4. Finally, add the outer folder `root_dir` to the workspace.

The general idea is to add folders to the workspace from innermost to outermost to see changes in all of them.

[A comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/37947#issuecomment-460340426) in that issue mentions another workaround, which is to create a `.gitmodules` file in the outer repository that VSCode will think means the repositories are organized as submodules (in which case changes in all will be seen), but then have `git` itself ignore the file.